# Machine Learning Method to Classify using Demand

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, geojson

I have the following scenario:

My input is a set of [points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvgky.png). Each point (Long_Lat coordinates) corresponds to the centroid of a subsection of a region, and has a **demand** for school. Like 50 children that need a school on the neighborhood.

After using a cluster method ([like k-means or DBscan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jk8v4.png)) to aggregate these Points by proximity, I want to allocate demand points to schools, in such a way that the cluster demands (the sum of all points demands on that cluster) are satisfied.

In other words, I want to create schools on that cluster and allocate the children (**points**) to these schools.

Schools have a **fixed capacity restriction**.

I.e.: I need 3 schools (capacity of 40), to suply the 100 children demand (P1, P2, P3) of cluster C4.

**Main objective** is, of course, to know the location of these schools. But I can retrieve it using logic.

What method should I use to fill the capacity of a cluster?
Is this the correct approach?

Comment: "Should" depends very much on your fitness criteria -- which you've failed to provide.  It seems that you've already solved a large portion of your allocation problem with k-means.  For instance, what happens when you set k=3 (for the three schools you have) and run k-means?  How does that not neatly solve your problem?  We need you to focus on the *specific* problem to make this appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sorry If could not be more specific. K-means and Dbscan are using only euclidian distance. How would I add the **demand** restriction to the clusterization?

Comment: "using Euclidean distance" drives the clustering.  I'm still not clear: does that also drive your placement of students?  Are you trying to minimize the total distance all students travel to school?  Do you need the optimum, or will an approximate "good" solution suffice?

Comment: What I really need is to create all the possible schools configurations, for the 3 schools sizes. After that I can solve the optimum using facility location (with gurobi). But first I need the initial points. Thought I could use ML to create them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For nicely distributed data, I expect that the most effective way will be to start with a k-means clustering.  If each resulting cluster fits within the schools' capacities, you have a solution.

However, your "worry" case is where at least one school is over capacity.  For instance, you have 20 children on the north side of a wide river, 90 on the south side, and the schools have a capacity of 40: you need to assign at least 10 children from the south to the north.

The algorithmic way to deal with this is to implement a different error function: add a clause that heavily penalizes (i.e. +infinity cost) adding a 41st student to that cluster.

Another way is to allow the clusters to aggregate normally, but adjust afterward.  Say that the SE school has 46 students, and the SW has 44: send the 6 and 4 students nearest to the the north school, to that school.

Is this enough guidance to work for you?  Do you have cases where you would have multiple schools both over and under capacity?  I don't want to over-engineer a solution.

Comment: After some digging I started to think that there is not a solution out of the box to this problem and began to think as you suggested. I think some modification on the DBscan with your reasoning will suffice, because I can generate the clusters using proximity, and checking the capacity one by one. Thanks!